# Managing iOS Devices

Tags: ios, provisioning, ipod-touch

I read the [Xcode 4 user guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215)

for managing my company's iOS device. I want to be able to test app on this iOS device.

My senior shared the provisioning profile with me. In the keychain I am able to see my certificate(labeled as VALID) & private key.

But in the Organizer - Devices window of Xcode. I am unable to see "valid certificate" in the Library-> provisioning Profile. Status is totally blank.

Pls help me out in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking. You need to provision your device at developer.apple.com if it is not provisioned for that app already.

Maybe this diagram will help:

[image]

Comment: Device is provisioned at developer.apple.com
I think, problem is with downloading appropriate provisioning profile. But The profile I downloaded, it is showing as a valid. So I am confused.? ;-)

Comment: My iPod has iOS 5.1 & xcode is 4.2
So is it the case that this version of xcode supports devices with only iOS<5.0 Thats why my device is not visible in schemes->iOS device

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these could be your answer:

1) Have you set the device for development? Do this by clicking on the button "Configure for development" from Organiser -> YourDevice

2) Add it manually from Organiser -> YourDevice -> Provisioning Profiles -> Click Add bottom left

3) Your device UDID must be included in the provisioning profile (do this through the iOS developer profile)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didnt helped me.